# Is it a way to add text beside img of button?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way get through to add text after img tag and it can be update everytime?
I'm using jsp and not support html5.

I have try through some example from here:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp

```html
<button type="button" class="button" id="updatetext" style="background-color:Transparent;background-repeat:no repeat;border:none;padding:25px">
   <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow_wide.jpg" height="85" width="85" align="left">
</button>
```

The Result:
The text inside the image can be update.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: try figcaption ... https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_figcaption.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
img {
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}

#some_id{
  color: white;

}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="button" id="updatetext" style="background color:Transparent;background-repeat:no repeat;border:none;padding:25px">
       <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-chinese-snack-and-chinese-tea-on-old-brown-wooden-table-in-dim-light-still-life-imge-and-select-1177215178.jpg" height="85" width="85" align="left"><p id = "some_id">text</p>
    
    </button>
```

then you can use jsp by referencing to id to update text

Comment: i need the text inside the image or beside the image can  be update.

Comment: can you give a screenshot of how the image is looking for you with this code

Comment: i have update the screenshot on top. thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [:after](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/sel_after.asp) or [:before](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/sel_before.asp) selector to append or prepend text after any element.

```css
img:after{
content: 'text after image'
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="button" id="updatetext" style="background-color:Transparent;background-repeat:no repeat;border:none;padding:25px">
   <img src="..\icon\press.png" height="85" width="85" align="left">

</button>
```

Comment: You can’t use pseudo elements on self closing tags like img

Comment: @mbharanidharan88  is it possible to put the text inside the image and the text might able to be update?

Comment: @Victor, Are you looking for this? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text_blocks.asp

Comment: @mbharanidharan88 yes, how to squeeze  the text inside the image?

Comment: @Victor, Can you please update the question with the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You need to link the html message to a variable using *jsp* annotations, in this case is: ***<%= Variable %>***, which will be updated somehow, also put a little bit of style on the page.

Try this:

```html
     <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
      <button id="button_test">
      <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/facebook-ui-colored/48/JD-22-64.png" alt="img"/>
        <div style="display:block;"><%= Variable %></div>
      </button>
        
    </div>
    
    </div>
```